# Importing Eclipse-generated GUI forms in to IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea, swingbuilder

I have a Java GUI application (Swing) that I built using Eclipse's designer. Most forms use Group layout, with the layouts/controls stuff written directly in the class constructor.

I have downloaded IntelliJ for evaluation, and succesfully imported my eclipse .project files and see them as modules in IntelliJ

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to understand this file and use its GUI designer? Right now, my form classes appear just as regular source code files.

Comment: look http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-opening-forms.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for what you want to do automatically.