# Is there a way that IntelliJ generates GUI designer code that is usable in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea, ide

I already tried the option to generate the designer code into the *.java files but this is not the complete code. Is there any other way to do that? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119743/importing-eclipse-generated-gui-forms-in-to-intellij?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is if you don't use IntelliJ layouts. Then it generates the whole code.